# Trouble installing Deco-IDE on Ubuntu 16.04 - .sh file keeps throwing a postscript ngrok error

Tags: ubuntu, error-handling

Ive been trying to install Deco-IDE on Ubuntu 16.04 linux through this hack I found on github but I keep getting an error seen in the image below after the lines:
cd ../../Desktop
npm install

I included a screenshot of the entire script bellow

I tried to manually install ngrok but still I get the same error.
Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image: error message after npm install]

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
npm -g install npm
```

instead of:

```
npm install
```

The reason being the npm you have is not the latest

Comment: Can you explain how/why this will help?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.